# Copy and split row by if cell condition it met - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to overcome the issue when I have a cell with specific char(';') which I would like to copy the same line with the amount if splitters that specific cell in specific col got.
For example:

| Index | Name | Age | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | 45 | Honda;Subaru |
| 2 | Oshir | 32 | BMW |

The result that I am trying to get is the following:

| Index | Name | Age | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | 45 | Honda |
| 2 | David | 45 | Subaru |
| 3 | Oshir | 32 | BMW |

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [Accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# set data and create dataframe
data = {"Name": ["David", "Oshir"], "Age": [45, 32], "Car": ["Honda;Subaru", "BMW"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.assign(Car=df['Car'].str.split(';')).explode('Car').reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

Returns

[image]